# Методы комбинирования вариаций

Tags: комбинаторика, методы

Я давно уже ищу наиболее разумный метод для реализации комбинирования чисел вперемешку с буквами, например. Примером может послужить государственный номер автомобиля. Сам номер состоит из 6 символов ( три числа в диапазоне 0-9 и три буквы в диапазоне а-я ), при чем буквы стоят на 1,5 и 6 местах, и регион, к где был зарегистрирован автомобиль. Буквы и цифры определенным методом комбинируют так, чтобы не было совпадений.  Так вот, какой метод комбинирования знаете вы? Рассмотреть можно на примере создания различных комбинаций из чисел: "1", "2", "3", "4"( и "5" можно...).

---

Иными словами, мне нужен метод брутфорса, перебора.

Comment: имхо, ничего не комбинируют. все номера выданные и невыданные как например бланки строгой отчетности уже есть в базе. по крайней мере выданные, а свободные легко находятся как:

    n=last+1;
    while (n in base) do n++;

количество номеров фиксированное, можно считать эти номера числовыми с переменной базой. серия из букв даст 12^3 номеров помноженное на 10^3 от номера. 1,7+млн номеров на регион. Если бы в номерах использовались 16-ричные числа, 6 значный номер давал бы 16+млн номеров (три байта), но в гаи работают не программисты, им проще иметь дело с нынешними номерами.

Comment: Неплохо! А метод комбинирования все-таки остался нераскрытым. =)

Comment: Ну так это и не ответ, а комментарий =)

Comment: Ну, в принципе, да)

Comment: а что мешает использовать обычный рандом?

Comment: @Spectre, рандом здесь не поможет. Рандом может повторяться и повторяется, если не изменить "зернышко"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Случай перебора возможных номерных знаков соответствует [**Размещению с повторениями**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) в комбинаторике. Ознакомиться со способом итерации по последовательностям таких элементов можно [**здесь.**](http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/file.php/21/razm_povt.doc)
- Для получения последовательности элементов *(если допускаются повторения)* из предопределенного набора достаточно `k` раз случайно выбирать какой-либо из этих элементов.
- Чуть интереснее случай, **когда повторения не допускаются** - тогда необходимо взять кортеж исходных допустимых элементов, например `{a, б, в, г, д, х, у, э}`, применить к нему операцию `shuffle` и взять первые `k` элементов.

> - Из известных мне способов `shuffl'инга` последовательности - наивный подход и [*алгоритм Кнута.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)
> - *Наивный подход* может быть описан так - сопоставить каждому допустимому элементу некоторое случайное значение с заданным отношением `<` и отсортировать последовательность на их основании.

Comment: Наконец-то вы))) Честно, вас и ждал)

------
А последняя ссылка - это что вообще?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, спасибо за полезные доки. Буду дерзать)